# Nested div elements not positioning as expected

Tags: html, css

I have the following html on a test page and I cannot understand why the nested div's position themselves +10 pixels below their parent. I expect them to all line up directly on top of the parent div. I tried setting the *box-sizing* and the *position* values to various combinations but they refuse to move. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="aj1"></div>
    <div class="aj2"></div>
    <div class="aj3"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/P8vAm/

Comment: Why are last three element inside the first one?

Answer (score 3):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.test div`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P8vAm/1/)

Or Add `font-size: 0;` to your `.test`

Comment: Or `font-size:0;` to `.test`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Has font-size always been factored into an elements height? I could swear that 4-5 years ago that this code worked without any font related adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

just add `line-height: 0;` to `.test`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
.test div{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9z6H/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by giving `float`.  Check this http://jsfiddle.net/P8vAm/6/